# Method error with multiple definition of the same submodule

Tags: julia

Imagine that I have the following module in a file `myMod.jl`:

```
module myMod

  type T
    i::Int
  end

  function sum(T1::T, T2::T)
    T1.i + T2.i  
  end

end
```

Now, I want to define two modules elsewhere that are able to use the type `T` defined in `myMod`, so let me write the following code:

```
# --- Define first module
module A

  include("myMod.jl")

  type Ta
    a::myMod.T
  end

end

# --- Define second module    
module B

  include("myMod.jl")

  type Tb
    a::myMod.T
  end

end

# --- Use the modules
using A, B

v1 = A.Ta(A.myMod.T(1))
v2 = B.Tb(B.myMod.T(2))
```

So far so good, everything works fine. I can even call the sum method with

```
A.myMod.sum(v1.a, v1.a)   # Returns 2, as expected
```

However, I can't sum `v1.a` and `v2.a`, despite `typeof(v1.a)` and `typeof(v2.a)` are both `T`:

```
A.myMod.sum(v1.a, v2.a)
```

> Error evaluating .../myTest.jl: `sum` has no method matching sum(::T,
>   ::T)

I have the feeling that though `v2.a` is of type `T`, Julia remembers that is has been created inside module B and thus doesn't recognize it as a T object.

Is there a workaround ? Or a more elegant/julianistic way of making the `sum` function work with both `v1.a` and `v2.a` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `include` function is basically the same as just pasting the code from myMod.jl into the location where `include` was called.  The way you're using it, it's as though you were defining two different modules, `A.myMod` and `B.myMod`, which happen to have the exact same implementation.  Although the two modules have identical implementations, they do not share the same identity.  Therefore `A.myMod.T` is not the same type as `B.myMod.T`.

What you want to do is define the `myMod` module just once, then use it when defining `Ta` and `Tb`.  You can do so using `using` as shown below.  I've assumed that `myMod` is still defined in the file myMod.jl, but you could just define them all in the same file if you wanted to.

```
include("myMod.jl")

# --- Define first module
module A

  using myMod

  type Ta
    a::myMod.T
  end

end

# --- Define second module    
module B

  using myMod

  type Tb
    a::myMod.T
  end

end

# --- Use the modules
using A, B, myMod

v1 = A.Ta(myMod.T(1))
v2 = B.Tb(myMod.T(2))
myMod.sum(v1.a, v2.a)
```